# Ordenar eventos en WordPress con "The Events Calendar"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy utilizando un plugin llamado "The Events Calendar" para organizar eventos. Por defecto, los ordena cronológicamente pero quiero hacerlo a la inversa.
He encontrado el codigo PHP que se debe colocar en functions.php pero al colocarlo la pagina revienta, en pocas palabras. No se carga ni hace nada. Sabeis que ocurre?.

```
    <?php
// Changes past event views to reverse chronological order
function tribe_past_reverse_chronological ($post_object) {
    $past_ajax = (defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX && $_REQUEST['tribe_event_display'] === 'past') ? true : false;
    if(tribe_is_past() || $past_ajax) {
        $post_object = array_reverse($post_object);
    }
    return $post_object;
}
add_filter('the_posts', 'tribe_past_reverse_chronological', 100);
```

Comment: Activa, si no está ya, el control de errores y dinos si sale algo al actualizar la pagina con ese código activado.

Comment: Lo forma de ordenar debe ser muy sencilla, algo como : `function tribe_past_reverse_chronological ($post_object) {
    $past_ajax = (defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX && $_REQUEST['tribe_event_display'] === 'past') ? true : false;
    if(tribe_is_past() || $past_ajax) {
        $post_object  ['order'] = 'ASC';
    }
    return $post_object;
}`
Aunque realmente no sé que significan tus referencias a Ajax en el código. Revisa este tipo de casos en el foro de ayuda, [por ejemplo este](https://theeventscalendar.com/support/forums/topic/change-sort-order-of-events-on-my-events-page/).